# Eloqua - Extract LastModifiedBy details of Security Group using REST API

Tags: rest, eloqua

I am trying to retrive security group details (last modified by field) using REST API,but unable to extract this information.

Here is my GET -

```
GET /Api/rest/2.0/system/security/groups?depth=partial&search=acronym%3DRXCM&xsrfToken=dfa16605-d884-4ebc-9a7b-16fd36c9181a
```

Response

```
{
  "elements":
  [
   {
    "type":"SecurityGroup",
    "id":"29",
    "createdAt":"1427641487",
    "createdBy":"13",
    "depth":"partial",
    "name":"Central Marketing User",
    "updatedAt":"1427641487",
    "acronym":"RXCM",
    "isEffective":"false",
    "isReadOnly":"false"
   }
  ],
  "page":1,
  "pageSize":1000,
  "total":1
}
```

Does anyone knows how to get LastModifiedBy field?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get more data on the response if you use the **depth=complete** instead of partial.
I'm not sure if that will return the LastModifiedBy.